# Prove {0^n OR 1^2n OR 2^3n | n >= 0} is not context free

Tags: turing-machines, regular-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

How to prove using pumping lemma {0^n OR 1^2n OR 2^3n | n >= 0} is not context free

This isnt the same language as {0^n1^2n2^3n | n >= 0} as this language the numbers need to be in order.

Answer (score 1):

It is not specified but I'll assume the alphabet to be $\Sigma = \{0,1,2\}$ and also that your *strange* notation means the language

\begin{align*}
L&= \{x \in \Sigma{}^* : x=0^n \lor x=1^{2n} \lor x=2^{3n}, n \in \mathbb{N}\} \\
 &=\{0^n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{1^{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{2^{3n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\}
\end{align*}

Well, the answer is that actually it **is** context-free since each of those three languages is trivially CF and the union of CFLs is also CF.

But it is also Regular!
By ***definition*** a language is said to be regular if it is accepted by some $DFA$ or, equivalently, if it is expressible by a regular expression.

In our case, $L = 0^*+(11)^*+(222)^*$.